Custom Event in golang and exported to New relic
I'm creating a custom event using opentelemetry in golang and exporting that to new relic. To getting that, I'm adding an Event to an span. So far so good.
...

// Start the server span
ctx, span := otel.GetTracerProvider().
    Tracer("Fibonacci").
    Start(ctx, r.Method+" /fibonacci", startSpanAttributes...)
defer span.End()

att1 := attribute.KeyValue{Key: attribute.Key("key1"), Value: attribute.StringValue("value1")}
att2 := attribute.KeyValue{Key: attribute.Key("key2"), Value: attribute.StringValue("value2")}
att3 := attribute.KeyValue{Key: attribute.Key("key3"), Value: attribute.StringValue("value3")}
span.AddEvent("my_custom_event", trace.WithAttributes(
    att1,
    att2,
    att3,
))

However, in new relic Metrics & Events browser the custom event is showed as SpanEvent and the 'my_custom_event' is showed as an attribute in 'Name' Columns.
I did the same using new relic agent and the 'my_custom_event' event is showed as event per se and the column "name" doen't exist.
New relic Metrics & Event Browser
... and my question is ... what should I do in opentelemetry to get the event as an event per se ?
Thanks.
Regards.
